# String.join freezes when one of the array elements is a flag emoji

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I have an iOS app which get an array of strings and joins them with spaces. Example: ["Foo", "Bar"] => "Foo Bar".

It happens that when one of the strings is a flag, for example USA flag, the app freezes completely using 100% of CPU. It happened the same on Playground.

It only happened with flags emoji AFAIK.

The code is something like this:

```
var array_with_flag = [""]
println(">> ".join(array_with_flag))
```

What can I do to fix it. Is there any reason to it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug in Swift. Just created a brand new single view app using Xcode 6.2, 6.4, and 7 beta 2 and all of them caused the same effect. You should [file a bug report with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). I just did, and filing duplicate reports will increase the efficiency of response.